# Select Values from two tables using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Hi I know this has been asked plenty of times, I'm not getting it through my skull

[How to select Values from several tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326092/how-to-select-values-from-several-tables)

I made these two Linq queries

First

```
                r = (from d in db.stageManagers 
                 where d.profileID == UserID && d.verticalID == VerticalID 
                 select new StageModels()
                 {
                     UserId = d.profileID,
                     VerticalId = (int)d.verticalID,
                     VerticalStageID = d.stageID
                 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Second

```
            r = (from d in db.stageManagerVerticals
                 where d.ID == r.VerticalId
                 select new StageModels()
                 {
                     VerticalName = d.verticalName
                 }
                 ).FirstOrDefault();
```

I want to make them one statement since they add data to one model and the tables they query have a **Pk Fk** relationship

In the *first block* **d.verticalId** is what I use to get the value(Name) in the *secondblock*, **d.verticalId** is primary key to *stageManagerVerticals* and foreign key in      *stageManager*, How can i join these queries ?

I tried this:

```
    r = (from d in db.stageManagers  
          join c in db.stageManagerVerticals on d.stageID  equals c.ID
                 where d.profileID == UserID && d.verticalID == VerticalID 
                 select new StageModels()
                 {
                     UserId = d.profileID,
                     VerticalId = (int)d.verticalID,
                     VerticalStageID = d.stageID;
                     VerticalName = c.verticalName
                 }
            ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What is the problem with what you have tried? Does it throw an exception? Wrong data?

Comment: What's wrong with your query ??

Comment: you tried to join with verticalId?

Comment: OK its my fault I added a semicolon instead of a comma, **VerticalStageID = d.stageID;**

Comment: Excuse me, lack of sleep,,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with [JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) in LINQ to select values from more than one table

eg:

```
var innerJoinQuery =
    from category in categories
    join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID
    select new { ProductName = prod.Name, Category = category.Name };
```

Comment: OK its my fault I added a semicolon instead of a comma, **VerticalStageID = d.stageID;**

Answer (score 1):

```
var leftOuterJoin=(c in categories
                   join p in products on c.ID equals p.CategoryID into t
                   from temp in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new { ProductName = p.Name, Category = c.Name }
                  ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the Navigational Properties,

```
var r = db.stageManagers.Where(x => x.profileID == UserID && x.verticalID == VerticalID).
            Select(
                d => new StageModels() {
                            UserID = d.profileID, 
                            VerticalID = (int)d.verticalID, 
                            VerticalStageID = d.stageID, 
                            VerticalName = d.stageManagerVertical.verticalName
                            }
                ).FirstOrDefault();
```